# Different mappings for stage and tarball

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to produce different log configuration for my stage app and on the tarball that I'd use to distribute my application

I have a task to generate the configuration and want it to be called with different parameters on doing stage and packageZipTar. This is my config

```
    mappings in Universal in stage += {
      val f = generateLoggingConfigTask(LogType.ConsoleAndFiles).value
      f -> ("conf/" + f.getName)
    },

    mappings in Universal in packageZipTarball += {
      val f = generateLoggingConfigTask(LogType.Files).value
      f -> ("conf/" + f.getName)
    },
```

The first task fires only when doing stage but on packageZipTarball I get both tasks running, furthermore they run in an unpredictable order so sometimes I have one config sometimes another

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `packageZipTarball` depends on `stage`, which is how native-packager works. `stage` always creates a "ready to build" directory, which the packaging format uses to create the package. Diverging these two, would be confusing and inconsistent with native-packagers behavior.

I would recommend one of the following options
1. Create your app with `stage` and pass the configuration explicitly with a cli parameter
2. Create a bash script that adds the logging configuration parameter explicitly and you call this to start your app